# How can I connect to WI-FI network when I can't put WPA2 password using the GUI?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, terminal

I am trying to connect to a WPA2 wi-fi network but when I click over the network it doesn't pop up any textbox where I can write the passoword as in the documentation. So I can't connect to the network.

How can I connect to a WPA2 network without using the GUI?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of raspbian?

Comment: @MohammadAli how can I check it?

Comment: Sudo apt-get update , and sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the guide: [Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.